# Homebrew: how to use the formula from the pull request

Tags: git, github-api

I'm new to GIT and GitHub (and Homebrew for that matter); the formula for emacs in the main repository is broken in OS X Lion, but there is a "pull request" (https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/6518) that fixes the problem (but it isn't merged in the main repository).

How can I update my local copy of the Homebrew repository to have that formula fixed ? If I manage that, will that formula still be updated if the main repository includes that fix ?

Please correct me if the terminology is not correct.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The documentation on [Github](http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/) describes that quite verbose (section *Merging a Pull Request*):

on your repo:

```
git checkout master
git remote add colin https://github.com/ColinHebert/homebrew.git
git fetch colin
```

Now, you have the full content of the `colin` repo (including knowledge of the commit hashes used in that repo). Next is to apply the changes. The docs say that you should do a `git merge`, but that's not so good in our case since colin added the changes to his `master`. If he works on `master` (and does some more commits), you'll get these changes too.

Fortunately, the four commits making up the patch are named in the Pull-request: `ae28b29e`, `df10b69a`, `e8915488`, `87f2d1e5`. You can apply them with [`git cherry-pick`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html):

```
git cherry-pick ae28b29e
git cherry-pick df10b69a
git cherry-pick e8915488
git cherry-pick 87f2d1e5
```

That's it. You could now delete the remote `colin` with

```
git remote rm colin
```

Another possibility would be to download the patch and apply it:

```
git checkout master
curl https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/6518.patch | git am
```

The patches for pull requests are always available via

```
https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/pull/<request_number>.patch
```

Comment: +1 A nice, clear answer - the tip about patches associated with pull requests may well come in handy.

Comment: @eckes: Thanks a lot. You said "that's not so good since colin added the changes to his master", but when I do the 'git fetch colin' I see " * [new branch]      emacs      -> colin/emacs", does that mean that I could fetch only the emacs branch of colin and then do a merge ?

Comment: @Cedric: well, it's worth a try :-) I don't know. Try it out.

Comment: This is helpful, but I don't know where the repository to update is!

Answer (score 58):

You can install a Homebrew formula directly from a pull request by using `brew install $raw_pull_requst_url`, eg:

```
brew install https://raw.github.com/ColinHebert/homebrew/538a99cc06a8f40b6ebcf2f4f8fd44d563c672cd/Library/Formula/emacs.rb
```

For finding the pull request URL, there's probably a better way, but I went to the pull request URL you linked, clicked on *Files Changed*, then on *View File @ 9b22d42*, then finally on *Raw*

Answer (score 16):

I found the following to be better for the casual homebrew user.

If you are searching for a fix there will be a pull number:

```
| => brew search vmdktool
No formula found for "vmdktool".
==> Searching pull requests...
Open pull requests:
vmdktool 1.4 (new formula) (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/9109)
```

Just do `brew pull ####` where `####` is the pull number:

```
| => brew pull 9109
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
Warning: Current branch is : do you need to pull inside master?
==> Fetching patch
Patch: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/9109.patch
==> Applying patch
Applying: vmdktool 1.4 (new formula)
==> Patch closes issue #9109
==> Patch changed:
 Formula/vmdktool.rb | 37 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 1 file changed, 37 insertions(+)
```

then do your install/upgrade:

```
| => brew install vmdktool
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated Homebrew from 11cf7b9 to 1f97e31.
No changes to formulae.

==> Using the sandbox
==> Downloading https://people.freebsd.org/~brian/vmdktool/vmdktool-1.4.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> make CFLAGS='-D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O -pipe'
==> make install PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/vmdktool/1.4
  /usr/local/Cellar/vmdktool/1.4: 4 files, 34.4K, built in 2 seconds
```

Comment: This is the easiest answer here - once you `brew search <new-formula-name>` and get told there is a pull request (github url/number), just `brew pull <request-number>`, then `brew install <new-pulled-formula-name>`, simples!

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I get the error `Error: No available formula with the name "libguestfs"`